# Defining observers with custom method names

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Apparently, setting a custom observer method name could be done in magento1:

```
<event name="controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after">
    <observers>
        <some_product_save>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Some\Module\Observer\Products</class>
            <method>doSomething</method>
        </some_product_save>
    </observers>
</event>
```

But in magento2, `method` attribute is [considered invalid](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/Test/Unit/Config/_files/invalidEventsXmlArray.php)

**Hence, how do I define an observer custom method name ?**

FYI, I don't want to use `execute` method because I think being forced to define N files/classes to listen to different events of the same resource would lead to an incredibly stupid amount of useless code (like 40 lines per class definition for only 5 lines of actually useful execute definition), considering that each class would need exactly the same context initialization.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't another way to do that. To properly execute observer you need to implement ObserverInterface. From an architectural perspective, it is easier to control dispatching events. It is easier to stick to the SOLID principle because from your perspectives you could have one class with thousands of methods that you can use for dispatching events.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time ! "from your perspectives you could have one class with thousands of methods" => No offense, I'm just speaking my mind: this seems to me like a very uneducated analysis. There are 2 main considerations there: 
1. you don't want to end up with 1000 methods in 1 class, but a) you can trust the dev not to do that b) it only make sense to group events of the same resource which will never be 1000.
2. code-effectiveness is strongly linked with cost-effectiness, so a design principle enforcing hardly 10% of code-effectiveness is unacceptable